# Android sending and listening for sms being sent

Tags: android, sms

as of right now here is what I have. However the client would now like to know if the sms was actually sent, and upon the send button being clicked they would like to return to the app.

how would you listen to see if the sms was sent? would it be in the activities onActivityResult()?
how would you tell the sms client to exit upon sending?
do I just need to make my own screen for sending the sms, and send the sms directly without launching a sms app?

```
    public static void launchSMSIntent(String to, String body, Context context)
    {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        if(to != null)
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", to);
        if(body != null)
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(smsIntent, Constants.SMS_INTENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to listen for the SMS being sent, you'll need to do it yourself via the android.telephony.SMSManager apis.  There's no way to guarantee that whatever random SMS app the user uses will return a flag to tell you whether it was sent or not.

Comment: I appreciate that as you say, "any old random app" doing the sending wouldn't notify this.  But is there a chance these days that, say, the built-in Message app, or perhaps "just on Samsung!" or something does in fact notify if an SMS is actually sent?  Any thought?  Cheers and thanks!

Comment: You could read the SMS context provider, there's ways to get all sent messages from that.  Check it say every 30 seconds for 5 minutes after you launch the intent.  If you're sending a particular piece of text that might work, but will miss some if they turn off the phone and come back later.  If you aren't, you can look at the timestamp and see if it happened soon after the activity was launched.  But that will have a moderately high false positive rate as well as the false negatives.

Comment: that's a fascinating tip @Gabe, thanks!  I will look in to reading the SMS context provider, and find out how to get all messages sent. Cheers!!